# Oshitaoshi ukemi name

Tags: aikido, falling

I am looking for the Japanese (or western) name of the breakfall uke does to escape from oshitaoshi. Basically, this is a half cart wheel that uke does when tori applies oshitaoshi.

In the drawing below, steps 7-9 are the break fall although in this illustration, uke's feet do not rise as much as we do -- probably because the drawing are done from a more static/slow technique instead of the explosive power we tend to use...

[image: Oshitaoshi]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In aikido, this is apparently called a "katate (single-handed) sokuten (cartwheel)" ukemi.

Reference: http://suigetsukan.org/aikido/aikido-techniques-list/

Also, in Bujinkan ninjutsu, they refer to this as a "katate oten" ukemi.

Reference: http://www.taijutsu.org.vt.edu/kihon.htm

There may be other names for it as well, depending on the martial art.